# Kerberos Configuration Manager - Does it work with SQL Server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, kerberos

I have just installed Kerberos Configuration Manager on a clustered SQL Server 2016 server and trying to connect using the app, it keeps failing.

I can connect using SSMS, but not with Kerberos Configuration Manager. I've tried leaving the fields empty and populating them, always fails.

Does anyone know if Kerberos Configuration Manager works with SQL Server 2016?

Answer (score 2):

This currently is not available yet for SQL Server 2016 unfortunately. You will have to manually add your SPN's using

```
 setspn –S MSSQLSvc/<server name>:1433 domain\account
```

**EDIT: The Kerberos Configuration manager is now available for SQL Server 2016**
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Answer (score 0):

As of Jan 2017 v3.1 is available to work with SQL 2016.  Link https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39046